# Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

Tell me why the execution of this program will take 10 seconds, not 15.

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    println("Start")
    val job = launch {
        repeat(5) {
            delay(1000)
            println(it)
        }
    }

    println("Suspending.....")
    delay(10000)
    println("Finish")
}
```

After all, the main stream will be used. Does this mean that we will simply skip the waiting part (and what will happen if this waiting is provided by a real delay, for example, when accessing the database, in a non-special delay function). Of course, delay is just a useless delay that can be simply removed.

Comment: What do you think `launch` does?

Comment: I know that launch launches a child coroutine in parallel, and if we had two threads, everything would be logical. But in this case, there is one stream, which means two coroutines will compete for one stream, and the total time should be 15 seconds, but in fact it turns out 10. So the delay part (namely 5 seconds) just skips. And for delay, this is acceptable, it's just a useless wait, but if there was a really heavy operation, it wouldn't have happened. That was the question.

Comment: What makes you think there is one stream?  Or that only one coroutine can run on a thread?  (Millions of coroutines can run at the same time, even on one thread.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "main stream will be used" I am assuming you mean that `runBlocking` by default is using only one thread. This is true, but `delay()` is suspending, so it doesn't block the thread it is called on. So when you launch this other child coroutine, it runs in parallel with the `delay(10000)` call below.

You are right that if these were blocking actions that took 5 seconds and 10 seconds respectively, the whole coroutine would take 15 seconds to complete because it wouldn't be able to run the launched child coroutine in parallel on the single-threaded dispatcher of `runBlocking`. If you used something like `runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) { }` so it isn't single-threaded, then it would still be able to run them in parallel.

Answer (score 3):

Because `launch` starts new coroutine. It is running in parallel with `delay(10000)`

See javaDoc for the `launch`

> Launches a new coroutine without blocking the current thread